# where func U256(n *big.Int) []byte is deined in v1.11.6

Tags: go-ethereum

Early version had module numbers.go, https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/v1.9.11/accounts/abi/numbers.go, which defines varios types and U256 function:

```
package abi

import (
    "math/big"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/math"
)

var (
    bigT      = reflect.TypeOf(&big.Int{})
    derefbigT = reflect.TypeOf(big.Int{})
    uint8T    = reflect.TypeOf(uint8(0))
    uint16T   = reflect.TypeOf(uint16(0))
    uint32T   = reflect.TypeOf(uint32(0))
    uint64T   = reflect.TypeOf(uint64(0))
    int8T     = reflect.TypeOf(int8(0))
    int16T    = reflect.TypeOf(int16(0))
    int32T    = reflect.TypeOf(int32(0))
    int64T    = reflect.TypeOf(int64(0))
    addressT  = reflect.TypeOf(common.Address{})
)
 
// U256 converts a big Int into a 256bit EVM number.
func U256(n *big.Int) []byte {
    return math.PaddedBigBytes(math.U256(n), 32)
}
```

where these definitions is done now?
where func U256(n *big.Int) []byte  is declared  in v1.11.6

Answer (score 0):

Was moved to [common/math](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/math#U256Bytes)

```
// U256Bytes converts a big Int into a 256bit EVM number.
// This operation is destructive.
func U256Bytes(n *big.Int) []byte {
    return PaddedBigBytes(U256(n), 32)
}
```